# How to select labels when both index and columns are named the same in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to find out the labels of the columns of nonzero elements of a particular row.

So for example:

```
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [3, 5, 2]], index=columns, columns=columns)
```

For column `a`, I would want to have `['a', 'c']` be returned.

Comment: @Merlin Yes, that is intentional

Comment: @Merlin nxn matrix, where indices are labels instead

Comment: Your data structure would have tough time passing a code review.

Comment: @Merlin Thanks for your constructive feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this look like something you want?

```
df.index[(df != 0)['a']]
# Index([u'a', u'c'], dtype='object')

df.index[(df != 0)['b']]
# Index([u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')

df.index[(df != 0)['c']]
# Index([u'a', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

To loop through the columns and build up a dictionary, we can do:

```
map(lambda col: {col: df.index[(df != 0)[col]].values}, df.columns)
# [{'a': array(['a', 'c'], dtype=object)},
#  {'b': array(['b', 'c'], dtype=object)},
#  {'c': array(['a', 'c'], dtype=object)}]
```

Comment: but is it possible to iterate through what that returns? I need it to be an iterable object.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean an object like a dictionary. What i meant was that I need as output an array of those columns because I eventually want to be able view those columns in the dataframe. Something like `df.loc[ thoseColumns, : ]`

Comment: Can you paste your desired output in your question?